# Escape symbols shown in "git log view" (C-x v l) in Emacs

Tags: git, logging, emacs, escaping

When doing C-x v l on a Git versioned file in Emacs, I get its recent history but with escape symbols ^[[...

See http://screencast.com/t/x1YWh4GKZR.

What's wrong in my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the git pager (Ex: 'git log' and 'git diff').

---

> This is due to the default pager which is `less`,
> because it cannot interpret correctly the escape characters.

---

#### Few solutions:

1. The first one is to change the pager to 'more':
   `git config --global core.pager more`
2. The second one is to append an additional command with `less -r`

   ```
   git diff --color | less -r
   git log -p --color | less -r
   // And you get a nice colored output.
   ```
3. This directly appends the modified less command when git pager is invoked to print correctly escape characters.
   `git config --global core.pager "less -r"`

Comment: `more` did work. I had the impression `less -r` did not, but I have troubles to reproduce the problem. Fixed. Thanks!